# Adding url parameters into AJAX call is causing PHP Notice

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have **AJAX** load-more code on my site, that pulls the latest posts and appends them to the bottom of the list.  This same code is also used in conjunction with some additional URL parameters, for custom filters `('?filter-id=')` and also *Wordpress Search* `('?s=')`.

The only way I could get these additional parameters to work with the AJAX is to add them into the AJAX wp-admin url in the localize scripts, like this:

```
       'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?s='.$_GET["s"].'&filter-id='.$_GET["filter-id"].'', // WordPress AJAX
   ) );
```

This works, the **AJAX** functions correctly in both search results and if a filter has been applied.  However, this code also throws out a **PHP** notice:

```
PHP Notice: Undefined index: s in /public/wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php on line 644

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: filter-id in /public/wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php on line 644
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The `Notice` appears because the `$_GET` array does not contain the elements `s` and `filter-id` that you are trying to access.

As a solution, I would suggest to collect all possible query parameters first, like this:

```
$queryParameters = [];

if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
    $queryParameters['s'] = $_GET['s'];
}

if (isset($_GET['filter-id'])) {
    $queryParameters['filter-id'] = $_GET['filter-id'];
}
```

Then you can later build your URL like this:

```
$url = sprintf(
    '%s/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?%s',
    site_url(),
    http_build_query($queryParameters)
);
```

And finally use it in your AJAX call:

```
'ajaxurl' => $url,
```

Splitting it up like that makes it more readable and thus easier extendible, if you want to add more parameters or some kind of validation later.

Answer (score -2):

well, this means that you don't have those keys in your $_GET array. So,
you should prepare the values before using them
to do that add them somewhere above with checking for existance.
For example,

```
///if those values can be empty, in your case that would be:

if (!isset($_GET[{YOUR_INDEX_HERE}]){
  $_GET[{YOUR_INDEX_HERE}]=''; 
}
```

OR

```
//if there should be some error checking
if (!isset($_GET[{YOUR_INDEX_HERE}]){
  //whatever check you need
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what does the @ do?

Comment: This answer simply suggests to hide the error and pretend it doesn't exist. This has the potential to cause other problems if the code later relies on these variables, and it also makes it harder to debug the code. Hiding errors is an anti-pattern. Fixing the errors would make a lot more sense

Comment: that is not an error, but notice about the undefined index. For production that will be hidden anyway, but for development that is shown for any undefined index. And it will work faster using this way instead of registration of all potential and not needed variables. Or it should be all predefined with many conditions before this portion of code. Like 
    if (!isset($_GET['s'])){
     // show some error here
    }
and so on for every single potential index

Comment: As noted by  ADyson, this answer demonstrate a bad practice and should be avoided. You're not solving anything here